# Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{3^k}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am looking at the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k $$

where $$a_k = \frac{k^2}{3^k}$$

The terms denominator grow much faster ([Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth)) than the numerators ([Quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_growth)) so I am guessing it will converge, but I also want to find the value of it since I am almost sure it does converge

Comment: What have you tried? You surely know of one or two tests to check convergence...

Comment: I think you can use ratio test ... but I also want to know how to actually find what the value, since I am almost sure it does converge

Comment: You can find the exact value! There is actually a really interesting method to reduce the sum you have to what is called an [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence), and then reduce that to a regular geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct - the sum converges. I will show this by showing that the sum, taken from the fifth term onward, converges. This is sufficient because the first four terms are finite.

---

Notice that for all $k>4$, $$2^k > k^2 \qquad \implies \qquad \frac{2^k}{3^k} > \frac{k^2}{3^k}$$

This implies $$\sum_{k=5}^\infty\, \left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^k \,>\, \sum_{k=5}^\infty \,\frac{k^2}{3^k}$$

But the left hand side is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with common ratio $2/3$, which we know converges. Therefore the right hand side (your sum) must converge.

---

Now that we know that it converges, suppose you'd like to find the exact value of the sum.

Let $S$ be the value to which your sum converges.

\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \,\frac{k^2}{3^k}\\\\
S&=0 + \frac{1}{3} +\frac{4}{9} + \frac{9}{27}+\frac{16}{81}+\frac{25}{243}+ \cdots\\\\
3S&= 1 + \frac{4}{3} +\frac{9}{9} + \frac{16}{27}+\frac{25}{81}+\frac{36}{243}+ \cdots
\end{align}

Now subtract the second-to-last equation above from the last equation. Let $R = 2S$ be this new series.

\begin{align}
3S - S &= 1 + \frac{3}{3} + \frac{5}{9} + \frac{7}{27} + \frac{9}{81} + \frac{11}{243} + \cdots \qquad \\\\
R &= 1 + \frac{3}{3} + \frac{5}{9} + \frac{7}{27} + \frac{9}{81} + \frac{11}{243} + \cdots\\\\
3R &= 6 + \frac{5}{3} + \frac{7}{9} + \frac{9}{27} + \frac{11}{81} + \frac{13}{243} + \cdots
\end{align}

Now subtract the second-to-last equation above from the last equation. Let $T = 2R = 4S$ be this new series.

\begin{align}
3R - R &= 5 + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{9} + \frac{2}{27} + \frac{2}{81} + \frac{2}{243} + \cdots \qquad \\\\
T &= 3 + 2 + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{9} + \frac{2}{27} + \frac{2}{81} + \frac{2}{243} + \cdots\\\\
T &= 3  + 2\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k}\right)
\end{align}

We've reached a geometric series with first term $1$ and common ratio $1/3$. This converges to $3/2$, so we are able to go back up the rabbit hole to find the value of $S$, at long last:

\begin{align}
4S &= 2R = T = 3 + 2(3/2) = 6 \qquad\qquad \\\\
S&=\boxed{\frac{3}{2}}
\end{align}

---

It's worth noting that series like the intermediate $R$ encountered here are called [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) because the terms' numerators are in arithmetic progression, while the denominators are in geometric progression.

Comment: @terrace Actually, the problem still exists for $k=4$, since $2^4 = 4^2$. So I made it from $k=5$ onward. But yes, the idea of the answer is still sound.

Comment: Alternative: for all $k\ge1$ we have $2.5^k>k^2$.

Comment: OOPS it's still wrong $5^2$ and $2^5$ doesnt work

Comment: @terrace I think it's actually correct right now, since $5^2 = 25 < 32 = 2^5$ ... however, using David's suggestion of $2.5^k$ would have probably been more convenient

Comment: yes $ \, $ $ \, $

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Consider $$a_k=k^2 x^k=k(k-1)x^k+k x^k$$ $$\sum a_k=x^2\sum k(k-1)x^{k-2}+x\sum k x^{k-1}=x^2 \left(\sum x^k \right)''+x \left(\sum x^k\right)'$$ Just finish and, at the end, replace $x$ by $\frac 13$ to get the value.

Comment: what is $ x \, \, $

Comment: @terrace. At the end $x=1/3$ for eveluating the summation.

Comment: yes sorry I saw the last sentence

Comment: I think subtracting $\sum$ from $3\sum$ repeatedly, as I did, is the analogue of taking a derivative in some way - I think this is because it's taking [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), which, for a polynomial, is similar to taking its derivative. Anyway, your solution is definitely much faster than mine, +1

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee. I agree with you, for sure. There are so many ways to do it ! Cheers.

Comment: how did you know to do this $x$ magic?

Comment: @terrace. $x^k=\frac 1{3^k}$ then ...

Comment: ok I think I understand thank you