# Validity of subtracting two infinite series to get the required sum of the original series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Like in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311566/961436 for evaluation of $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{3^k}$   . I evaluated by same method although i used a bit different way by first dividding by 3 whole series , but i would like to know when we do not care of the last terms in a infinite series , is it when we know that last term tends to zero ?

> Like here we have a series of $X = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{4}{9}...$ and another series of $Z= \frac{X}{3}$ but what i did was subtracted from X by shifting one term each of the Z series , that will leave me with some series but should we care of the last term which got remain in the Z series which didnt get subtracted at all from a X series term , or we reason it as last term tends to zero in both series X and Z so we dont need to care of that ?

- Note : Although i got the same answer by subtracting and then again dividing by 3 and again subtracting to get a AGP which got me answer as 3/2 . **i was just checking the validity in subtracting two infinite series shifted by one term**

Comment: If $~\langle a_n\rangle, ~\langle b_n\rangle~$ are two convergent sequences that converge to $L_1, L_2$ respectively, then $~\langle (a_n + b_n)\rangle~$ is a convergent sequence that converges to $(L_1 + L_2)$.  Note that any convergent series can be construed to be a convergent sequence of partial sums.  That is, the series $k_1 + k_2 + \cdots$ can be construed to be the sequence $(k_1), (k_1 + k_2), (k_1 + k_2 + k_3), \cdots$.

Comment: Infinite series has no last term.

Comment: Yeah that i understood but if we do the addition or subtraction with one term or say 20 terms shift will then also value will be same come out ? , And what we should give the reason for neglecting the last terms as such in the method above ?  Although i know infinite series has no last term but thats doesnt quite a good reason for me @user2661923

Comment: I mean in my case i know both X/3 and X converge but i want to know how we are not taking consideration of final terms which for finite case makes sense there would be some terms

Comment: I didn't read your posting closely enough.  This is why my last comment was not on point.  Given two convergent infinite sequences, before you add them, term by term, you are free to re-index them, as long as you don't change the order of the terms.  So, for example, you could construct $\langle c_n\rangle$ by $c_n = 0 ~: n \leq 20$ and $c_n = a_{n-20} : n > 20.$

Comment: Okay i see , lets say we add those two (-R ) and X and  suppose we get something like 1 +1/2 +1/4 +1/8.... - 1/3^k  for some finite k Is it necessary we dont write what the last term is or as in we dont care in case k goes to infinity because we know starting terms matters last terms dont change anything ?